# Oracle Spatial function SDO_CS.Transform(value) results really slow

Tags: oracle, geometry, spatial-query, spatial-index

I have a custom view which queries spatial data from geometry columns and extracts latitude/longtitude values. However, the retrieval process is really slow, and takes upto 5 to 10 mins for the view data to be retrieved.

Here is my view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW PoleData
(
   G3E_FID,
   X_COORD,
   Y_COORD,
   LATITUDE,
   LONGITUDE
)
AS
   SELECT P.g3e_fid,
          T2.X * 1000 AS x_coord,
          T2.Y * 1000 AS y_coord,
          T.Y AS latitude,
          T.X AS longitude
     FROM PolePoint P,
          TABLE (
             SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (SDO_CS.TRANSFORM (P.G3E_GEOMETRY, 8265))) T,
          TABLE (SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (P.G3E_GEOMETRY)) T2
    WHERE P.ltt_id = 0
   UNION
   SELECT P.g3e_fid,
          T2.X * 1000 AS x_coord,
          T2.Y * 1000 AS y_coord,
          T.Y AS latitude,
          T.X AS longitude
     FROM PoleDetailPoint P,
          TABLE (
             SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (SDO_CS.TRANSFORM (P.G3E_GEOMETRY, 8265))) T,
          TABLE (SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (P.G3E_GEOMETRY)) T2
    WHERE P.ltt_id = 0;
```

The `G3E_GEOMETRY` column is of `SDO_GEOMETRY` type. PolePoint table has 1,310,629 rows while PoleDetailPoint has 100. The data in this tables are updated on a daily basis, while the view is used for reporting purposes.

I tried rebuilding the spatial index using the `status=cleanup` parameter. But that didn't make any difference.

Our version is Oracle 11.2.0.3.

Any tips on retrieving such type of views/data appreciated. Or any other spatial functions that I can use to achieve this faster?

Comment: wHY WAS THE QUESTION DOWNVOTED? can the user who downvoted comment the reason?

Comment: If there is no overlap in PolePoint and PoleDetailPoint, you could use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` then the DB won't have to make the results distinct.

Comment: Do you really need `Union`? why you don't use `union all`?

Comment: if this is for reporting, why not just build a materialized view?  Refresh it once/day, and put an index or two on it, and you can query it lickity split.

Comment: Don't have time at hand and data to fiddle with it, but I would try to hint the first statement to use hash between the main table and the hidden table that supports the nested table used for spatial column. I suspect a NL using the index on nested table. Can you please post the execution plan?

Comment: How exactly do you query this view?  And like Florin suggested, an explain plan would be useful.  Generate one like this: `explain plan for select * from PoleData;` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  The performance may have nothing to do with SDO, it may just be a bad execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`:

```
SELECT P.g3e_fid,
       T2.X * 1000 AS x_coord,
       T2.Y * 1000 AS y_coord,
       T.Y AS latitude,
       T.X AS longitude
  FROM PolePoint P,
       TABLE (
          SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (SDO_CS.TRANSFORM (P.G3E_GEOMETRY, 8265))) T,
       TABLE (SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (P.G3E_GEOMETRY)) T2
 WHERE P.ltt_id = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT P.g3e_fid,
       T2.X * 1000 AS x_coord,
       T2.Y * 1000 AS y_coord,
       T.Y AS latitude,
       T.X AS longitude
  FROM PoleDetailPoint P,
       TABLE (
          SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (SDO_CS.TRANSFORM (P.G3E_GEOMETRY, 8265))) T,
       TABLE (SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (P.G3E_GEOMETRY)) T2
 WHERE P.ltt_id = 0;
```

Another potential source of performance degradation comes from the fact that you are using two calls to `SDO_UTIL.GET_VERTICES` one directly on `P.G3E_GEOMETRY` and the other on a transform of `P.G3E_GEOMETRY` you will essentially have a cross product of the two vertices lists, so for example if a particular `P.G3E_GEOMETRY` contains 5 vertices, then you will end up with 5 * 5 records one for each of the 25 possible combinations of T and T2 for that 5 vertex `P.G3E_GEOMETRY`.  I don't know if the vertex order is maintained by the `SDO_CS.TRANSFORM` function, but if it is, you could improve your performance by adding the `and t1.id = t2.id` predicate to each half of your query:

```
SELECT P.g3e_fid,
       T2.X * 1000 AS x_coord,
       T2.Y * 1000 AS y_coord,
       T.Y AS latitude,
       T.X AS longitude
  FROM PolePoint P,
       TABLE (
          SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (SDO_CS.TRANSFORM (P.G3E_GEOMETRY, 8265))) T,
       TABLE (SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (P.G3E_GEOMETRY)) T2
 WHERE P.ltt_id = 0
   AND T.ID = T2.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT P.g3e_fid,
       T2.X * 1000 AS x_coord,
       T2.Y * 1000 AS y_coord,
       T.Y AS latitude,
       T.X AS longitude
  FROM PoleDetailPoint P,
       TABLE (
          SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (SDO_CS.TRANSFORM (P.G3E_GEOMETRY, 8265))) T,
       TABLE (SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES (P.G3E_GEOMETRY)) T2
 WHERE P.ltt_id = 0
   AND T.ID = T2.ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to move the cast to table elements to a with clause?

Normally they are very slow, especially if the optimizer decides to run them for every row in the joining table (to check if the result set has changed)

Try this:

```
with t as (select * from table (sdo_util.getvertices (sdo_cs.transform (p.g3e_geometry, 8265)))),
     t2 as (select * from table (sdo_util.getvertices (p.g3e_geometry)))
select p.g3e_fid,
       t2.x * 1000 as x_coord,
       t2.y * 1000 as y_coord,
       t.y as latitude,
       t.x as longitude
  from polepoint p, t, t2
 where p.ltt_id = 0
union 
select p.g3e_fid,
       t2.x * 1000 as x_coord,
       t2.y * 1000 as y_coord,
       t.y as latitude,
       t.x as longitude
  from poledetailpoint p, t, t2
 where p.ltt_id = 0;
```

Also,  are you sure that you need `"union"` (forced sort filter) instead of `"union all"`?  (i.e. do you expect duplicate results? If not use `union all`)

Regards
Olafur

Comment: You can't pull the cast to table elements out with a with clause since they depend on the polepoint table. Notice the p.g3e_geometry references.

Comment: Ah, yes of course.  I see it now. But that explains why it's so slow.  table(sdo_util.getvertices(...)) is being run 2 times for every single row in polepoint  and 2 times for every single row in poledetailpoint.